# How can I assign the output of this command to a variable in Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following command:

```
egrep -e "\\\\" pom.xml | egrep -v -e "\\\\$"
```

I want to assign it to a variable so that I can echo it later in this code:

```
egrep -e "\\\\" pom.xml | egrep -v -e "\\\\$"  &> /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   echo "Errors in POM were found"
   echo "line matches (result of the command)"
fi
```

Comment: Be aware that, depending on your shell and the version thereof, the return value of the pipeline could be the first command or the last command.  You could probably just stick a period at the end of your pattern in the first grep and have the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
POM_ERRORS=$(egrep -e "\\\\" pom.xml | egrep -v -e "\\\\$")
```